# Why does `BasicObject` answer methods `superclass` and `class`?

Tags: ruby

If `Object < BasicObject`, and `#superclass` and `#class` are defined in `Object`, how it possible that `class A < BasicObject` answers to `A.superclass` and `A.class`? `A.ancestors`: `[A, BasicObject]`

Going further (according to new answers):

If `A` is an instance of `Object` why doesn't it have it in its ancestors?

```
Class B;end
B.ancestors # => [B, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

`SuperClass` might be defined in `Kernel`, but `A` doesn't have `Kernel` in its ancestors.

`Kernel` is included in `Object` (from [`object.rb`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html)):

```
class Object < BasicObject
  include Kernel
end
```

**P.S** This [git issue](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/426) confused me enough to ask about it

Comment: Not sure what `B` is doing.

Comment: If it was the case that `A.new.class` was returning something your question would make sense. `class A < BasicObject` means `A` inherits from `BasicObject`, not `A` is an instance of `BasicObject`. `A` is still an instance of `Class` and therefore of `Object`.

Comment: Don't add new questions to the same thread. If you have additional questions, make a new post.

Comment: You have to differentiate between inheritance and instantiation. `A.ancestors` will give you the names of the classes and modules where methods will be looked if you try to access them on **instances** of class `A`. If you want to see the ancestor chain for where methods will be looked if you want to call them on `A` directly, you have to do `A.class.ancestors`.

Comment: @ndn good point, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A < BasicObject
end
```

Here, the **class** `A` is itself an instance of the class [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Class.html).

```
A.class
#=> Class
```

`A` answers to `.class` and `.superclass` because `Class` supports them.

What you are thinking is an **instance** of `A`, in that case:

```
A.new
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because `A` (as well as `BasicObject`) is an instance of the `Class` class, on which `superclass` is defined, and `Class` is a subclass of `Object`, which includes `Kernel`, on which `class` is defined.

```
BasicObject.method(:superclass).owner # => Class
BasicObject.method(:class).owner # => Kernel
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are not correct.

`#class` is defined as an instance method of `Kernel`:

```
From: object.c (C Method):
Owner: Kernel
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 5

VALUE
rb_obj_class(VALUE obj)
{
    return rb_class_real(CLASS_OF(obj));
}
```

and `superclass` is defined as an instance method of `Class`:

```
From: object.c (C Method):
Owner: Class
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 17

VALUE
rb_class_superclass(VALUE klass)
{
    VALUE super = RCLASS_SUPER(klass);

    if (!super) {
    if (klass == rb_cBasicObject) return Qnil;
    rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "uninitialized class");
    }
    while (RB_TYPE_P(super, T_ICLASS)) {
    super = RCLASS_SUPER(super);
    }
    if (!super) {
    return Qnil;
    }
    return super;
}
```

Comment: Kernel is included inside Class class. BasicObject doesn't have anything from Kernel, right? See update

Answer (score 0):

`BasicObject` has a minimal set of **instance methods**, but it has as many common **class methods** (instance methods of `Class` class) as other classes, that's why you can call `BasicObject.class`. Also remember that `BasicObject` itself is an `Object`, and all instances of `Object` have the method `class`, so does `BasicObject`.